# How to set title in the MFMailComposerViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to set the title of MFMailComposerViewController , which is a subclass of UINavigationController.

I am using these following ways :

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 [picker.navigationController navigationItem].title = @"Send Mail";
 [[picker navigationItem] setTitle:@"Send Mail"];
```

But I am not able to set the Title.

Am i doing it wrong ??
   Is there any other method to do so ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is updated whenever the subject changes. You cannot change the title programmatically within AppStore restrictions. You may use `-setSubject:` to initialize the subject.

(A bad way to solve this is to create a very high-level window with a label that covers original title. This is very difficult to make this work with orientation change.)